# Duplicate key-sequence ['validation'] in key identity-constraint 'itemName'

Tags: magento2.3

I am facing Below issue,

1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'item': Duplicate key-sequence ['validation'] in key identity-constraint 'itemName'.
Line: 1350

Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Config\Dom\ValidationException): Element 'item': Duplicate key-sequence ['validation'] in key identity-constraint 'itemName'.
Line: 1350

As I checked Xml File with "**item name="validation"** "But its showing in 84 files, It will make me risky to change it on files

Can any one help me to resolved it

Answer (score 1):

I found solution, as there was two times declaration for **item name="validation** in same xml value with same content.

```
<item name="xyz">
      <item name="validation">some code</item>
      <item name="validation">some code</item>
</item>
```

Comment: can you add screen short of same xml value ? mean post here in your answer what was actually you removed?

Comment: Hi Hasssan, Currently I have dint Have screenshot and such kind of scanario. But I can give some short code, Updating My ans.

Comment: ok I am waiting for this thanks in advance

Comment: In my case <item name="validation"> is twice in one item node.

Answer (score 0):

See you facing this issue by adding a new module or some custom code it won't just pop up out.

So, just disable or remove duplicate validation in same argument what you have added recently or just go and find it in the same.

Happy Coding